# what is role of Toast's setMargin in android?

Tags: android, toast

I'm developing an app that float Toast. so I made the following code. but In the following code, I don't know what role setMagin has. to know the role, I entered android studio homepage. there following expression was written. to be honest, I don't know although see that. I will also upload run screen.
I wonder why toast message is on top and right side. please let me know that!!
following code(design) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="floatToast"
        android:onClick="toastClick"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

following code(code) :

```
package org.techtown.samplelayoutinflater;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void toastClick(View view){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "hello world", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setMargin(20, 20);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

following expression :
[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that the values are `float`s and the doc say `in percentage`, so try passing a value between 0.0f and 1.0f. It's probably clamping to 1 so you get the toast at the extreme edge of the screen.

Comment: what mean is "clamping to 1"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamping_(graphics). "clamp" is "keep a value within a range", in this case 0 to 1. So if you pass 20 it will be "clamped" to 1. If you pass -20, it will be "clamped" to 0. If you pass 0.5 it will not be "clamped" because it's in range.